# How to search podcasts using spoken audio?

Tags: podcasts

I remember seeing this alert:

> [image]
>
> new in Apple podcasts
> search the audio beta
> type to find topics and people mentioned in the audio.

I have since dismissed that pop up and have never seen it again. Now when I go to search for something, it only returns me results that match in the title or show description. How do I search based off of the spoken words?